# How to make the text center in TabPageIndicator

Tags: android, android-layout, styles

hi，guys，i use TabPageIndicator in my app，everything is ok.eh,but the PageTitle can not be in center like this:
[image]

as u see,it is on left.
i try to use a custom style：

```
    <style  name="LightTabPageIndicator"  parent="Material.Widget.TabPageIndicator">
        <item name="tpi_tabPadding">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="tpi_tabRipple">@style/LightTabRippleStyle</item>
        <item name="tpi_indicatorHeight">3dp</item>
        <item name="tpi_indicatorColor">@color/md_blue_400</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/LightTabTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/md_grey_200</item>
        <item name="tpi_mode">fixed</item>
    </style>
    <style name="LightTabRippleStyle" parent="Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave">
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="rd_rippleColor">@color/md_grey_500</item>
        <item name="rd_rippleAnimDuration">300</item>
        <item name="rd_maskType">rectangle</item>
        <item name="rd_cornerRadius">0dp</item>
        <item name="rd_padding">0dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="LightTabTextAppearance" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead">
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/color_tpi_dark</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

but it does not work.
so how to make it work? thanks for u view and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Use android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec#setIndicator(CharSequence label) for each added tab

```
int tabCount = tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount();
for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
    final View view = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);
    if ( view != null ) {
        // reduce height of the tab
        view.getLayoutParams().height *= 0.66;

        //  get title text view
        final View textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        if ( textView instanceof TextView ) {
            // just in case check the type

            // center text
            ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            // wrap text
            ((TextView) textView).setSingleLine(false);

            // explicitly set layout parameters
            textView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
            textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eh,i must use TabPageIndicator + ViewPage.so it is not OK.But thanks all the same.